# How to create donut-pie chart using c3-chart in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, charts, c3.js

I am trying to create [donug-pie chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut) using c3-chart. i don't want to use highcharts if its possible to do it using c3-chart. Is there a way?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the [c3-angular-directive](http://jettro.github.io/c3-angular-directive) library to build the donught chart using c3 with angular js. Refer the [Examples](http://jettro.github.io/c3-angular-directive/#examples) section on how to use.